# Disable IPad layer on "focus"

Tags: css, ipad, focus, layer

I couldn't find anything on Google, I hope anyone has an answer!

When I touch an element which can receive focus such as an `map` shape or a "same-page" `<a>` on IPad I can see a black semi-opaque layer above the element.

I just want to define MY behaviour of focus or equivalent on these elements, but I didn't find how to disable this layer!

Is there possible??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:<css-color>
```

There is already an article on stackoverflow:
[-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); on a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974687/webkit-tap-highlight-color-rgba0-0-0-0-on-a-div)

Report to this manual: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html

Comment: I could not find by searching with my tags..! Thanks!