# iPad canvas flickers when tapped

Tags: ipad, canvas

Trying to create a PhoneGap app using the canvas tag on an iPad.  The animations work fine and great but there is a blink whenever the canvas is tapped.

The same thing happens on my iPad when I go check sites with the canvas tag as well...

Does anyone know how I might prevent this?

Comment: Could you try setting the CSS rule `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` to `transparent` on the canvas and seeing if that does the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having your event handler consume the event and prevent it propagating to the browser.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

In my canvas app, to keep the event from all browsers, I actually use whatever's available from event.stopPropagation(), event.stopImmediatePropagation(), event.preventDefault(), and then also have the handler return false.  Can't remember which platform required which, but the linked doc suggests event.preventDefault() for Safari.

Answer (score 15):

This bit of CSS fixed it for me:

```
<style>
    * { -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); }
</style>
```

See also [-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); on a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974687/webkit-tap-highlight-color-rgba0-0-0-0-on-a-div)

Comment: It's important to note that this needs to be applied to the container with the click/touch event, not necessarily the <canvas> In my case, I needed to add this to the parent container that had the event registered to it.  Also.. thanks!!!