# remove orange outline from focused element in samsung galaxy s2

Tags: html, css, samsung-mobile, outline

Is there a way to turn off the highlight effects used by the mobile browser in the samsung galaxy s2 ?

I already tried:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
outline:none;

-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

alternatively - can someone explain exactly When those effects show?
can I detect a screen touchstart and touchend in a way that does not trigger those effects?

Thanks

Comment: I not shure if this will solve your problem but did you try `a:focus { outline: none }`?

Comment: Do you expect the :focus selector to affect any html tag? or does it work only on "A" tags? basicly my issue is not with a tags but with divs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS:

```
.borderImage {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="borderImage">
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
</div>
```

Found here ;) : [-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); on a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974687/webkit-tap-highlight-color-rgba0-0-0-0-on-a-div)

Edit (nice to know):

```
/* No background, just iOS:*/
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

/* No background iOS + Android:  */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: turns out the problem was that my CSS selector didn't actually hit the desired html elements...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `e.preventDefault();` on the touch start event.

Comment: I noticed that your response was originally "We had the same problem ...". I am not sure why was this edited out... this is definatly not a me too but a strong indication that you actually resolved the issue - am I right about that ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```